# How should I tune an Ubuntu server for many high memory php-cli processes causing high load with good hardware?

Tags: php, vmware, cpu-usage, ram, ubuntu-server

I run many php-cli scripts via crontab on an Ubuntu server running within VMWare VSphere. The PHP scripts are memory hogs (fixing that simultaneously) but it seems they should have the resources needed on this VM. The load average is very high in the 100+ range with a high-performance 8core and 120G ram box. I'm puzzled why the load is high when I see:

1. large amount of memory free
2. no swapping
3. top reports 80+ CPU idle

Environment info:

```
#uname -a
Linux tasks 3.0.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 7 20:48:45 UTC 2011 x86_64     GNU/Linux
```

The following items have been adjusted in sysctl:

```
#head /etc/sysctl.conf
fs.file-max = 2097152
vm.swappiness = 10
vm.dirty_ratio = 60
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 2
```

top

```
top - 10:51:27 up 219 days, 21:50,  3 users,  load average: 190.18, 171.37, 152.70
Tasks: 400 total, 179 running, 220 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
%Cpu(s): 11.4 us,  1.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 86.2 id,  0.4 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
Mb Mem:    121121 total,    51993 used,    69128 free,       17 buffers
Mb Swap:     6257 total,        0 used,     6257 free,      532 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                  
10551 root      20   0  557m 282m  11m R   1.7  0.2   0:05.83 php                      
 6204 root      20   0  555m 286m  10m R   1.0  0.2   0:07.41 php                      
16516 root      20   0  408m 140m 9744 R   1.0  0.1   0:03.34 php                      
24167 root      20   0  309m  41m 9784 R   1.0  0.0   0:00.63 php                      
45041 root      20   0 1894m 1.6g  10m R   1.0  1.3   7:27.72 php                      
  599 root      20   0  521m 254m  10m R   0.7  0.2   0:09.26 php                      
 1101 root      20   0  357m  89m 9796 R   0.7  0.1   3:46.28 php                      
 3273 root      20   0 3342m 3.0g 9756 R   0.7  2.5   3:50.18 php                      
 3958 root      20   0  536m 268m  10m R   0.7  0.2   0:08.28 php                      
 4798 root      20   0  780m 508m 9756 R   0.7  0.4   0:08.26 php                      
 5464 root      20   0  532m 256m  10m R   0.7  0.2   0:08.03 php                      
 5905 root      20   0  536m 268m  10m R   0.7  0.2   0:07.42 php                      
 6913 root      20   0  557m 288m  10m R   0.7  0.2   0:06.89 php                      
 7028 root      20   0 2147m 1.8g 9792 R   0.7  1.6   0:32.89 php                      
 8535 root      20   0  431m 156m  10m R   0.7  0.1   0:06.77 php                      
 8745 root      20   0 2836m 2.5g  10m R   0.7  2.1   4:46.24 php                      
 9224 root      20   0  538m 269m  10m R   0.7  0.2   0:06.36 php                      
10665 root      20   0  745m 473m 9752 R   0.7  0.4   0:05.96 php                      
12313 root      20   0  760m 490m 9752 R   0.7  0.4   0:05.15 php                      
12340 root      20   0  944m 675m 9752 R   0.7  0.6   0:05.15 php
```

vmstat

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
191  1      0 70536200  18216 546040    0    0     0    32 3007 2381 13  2 85  0
187  0      0 70567328  18216 546068    0    0     0     4 2840 2468 12  1 86  0
184  0      0 70650144  18216 546096    0    0     0     0 3802 2655 10  2 88  0
186  0      0 70642768  18216 546120    0    0     0     0 4456 2431 13  1 86  0
186  0      0 70630560  18216 546144    0    0     0     0 4936 2629 15  2 83  0
185  1      0 70620504  18224 546152    0    0     0    32 4584 2459 12  2 86  0
183  0      0 70611000  18224 546192    0    0     0     4 3820 2827  9  2 89  0
190  1      0 70643592  18224 546260    0    0     0     0 4093 3350 12  3 84  1
191  0      0 71065760  18224 546304    0    0     0     0 3745 2503 12  3 84  0
191  4      0 71041560  18224 546332    0    0     0     0 3314 2798 13  2 85  0
187  0      0 71028392  18224 546332    0    0     0     0 3280 3140 12  2 86  0
195  0      0 71015808  18236 546360    0    0     4   240 3164 2945 14  2 84  0
196  0      0 71002112  18236 546388    0    0     0     0 3136 3004  9  2 89  0
194  0      0 70999600  18236 546416    0    0     0     0 3576 3348 14  2 83  0
187  1      0 70994792  18236 546436    0    0     0     0 3362 3193 13  2 85  0
188  0      0 70979392  18236 546448    0    0     0     0 2870 3054 10  2 88  0
```

What other tools or settings I should be reviewing?

**UPDATE**
Running htop I can see a single core is handling all PHP processes. Is there perhaps a setting on the VM or OS which would control this?

Comment: Are these stats from within a VM or on the host machine?

Comment: What do the scripts do? Are they all the same?

Comment: @Chad they are stats from the vm. The host machine is healthy.

Comment: @halfer the scripts aren't all the same. They are cakephp shell scripts so there is high memory from loading that framework. The scripts are being tuned further as I know there is much room for improvement, but I'm primarily wanting to understand why the server is not allowing the php scripts to fully utilize the cpu and ram available to it.

Comment: Something that _may_ impact it is that PHP is only single threaded so each process will only use 1 CPU.  I'm unsure how the process allocation happens (I believe it's up to the OS) but potentially you have a bunch of processes utilizing a subset of the CPUs which may skew the load average.  E.g. if you have 30 processes utilizing a single CPU, it may push the load very high but still allow for low utilization.

Comment: @Chad thank you, this got me thinking about how these processes are started. If I run "ps -eF" I can see that the PSR for many of these is "1" which I believe means they are all fighting for the same processor. The bulk of the scripts are started from a primary PHP script via:
exec("/path/to/php-script > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");

Comment: @Kenny Np.  You might also (if you're not already familiar) want to look into CPU affinity.  That may be a way for you to adjust the usage.

Comment: Just asking: is it normal for php processes to run as root?

Answer (score 0):

Your load average is exactly as expected -

You have 100+ processes running. They're all running at the same time. Therefore your load average should be 100+.

It's a very rough indicator of 'how much stuff is going on right now on the machine' - and the answer is - a lot! You have a 100 processes running all at the same time right now.

When your processes are waiting for I/O requests to complete, they're considered 'not running' - so your load average would be lower.

It looks to me like everything is working as expected! Except for that thing where they're all running on the same CPU.

But if they were all running on different CPU's, your load average would be the same. Your CPU usage (in aggregate) would be higher.

Now - if the various processes that you're running are taking too long - that's a different thing. But, again, your load average would still be high.

As for another troubleshooting tool - in top you can type '1' and it should show you a breakout of all of your CPU's.

And "iostat" is a good tool for seeing if you are I/O-constrained. Which I doubt you are; since your load average is so high (you'd see a higher percentage in "wa" which means "waiting"). If you try something like "iostat 5" you will get a refresh of I/O usage every 5 seconds, for example. If you see one of your disks getting slammed, that would be something you could try to fix, either in code, or with faster disks, or RAID, or caching, or something like that.